# How to query on a pandas data frame based on column values of specific row

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

[image]

and I would like to select all rows which have the same values for 'x1' and 'x2' as the first row.

I know that I can query the data frame after I get the values of x1 and x2 for this code. However, I want more general way if I had more features than x1 and x2, say I would like to do the same on 100 feature. is there a way that I can take the similar values?

I also thought about group by, then choose the group which contains this row, but I think ofc there will be other better ways

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
cols = ['x1','x2']
df[df[cols].eq(df.iloc[0][cols]).all(1)]
```